# Paypal LiveI transactionSearch API type changes over time

Tags: paypal

We are currently using an app which performs transactionSearches of customer PayPal accounts via SOAP API interface.
I have noted that in some cases the following can occur:

1. An initial Payment transaction is created for an amount, with status=Completed.
2. At a later time eg 1 hour, a second transaction (with different id) is created for the same amount, and the type of the first transaction (keyed by transactionId) changes to Authorized.

We are unable to correlate the second transaction as being for the same payment (they are) for our standard transactionSearch calls.

Does anyone know how these steps can occur in a payment process? I can understand a single payment transaction initially being created with status=Authorized, and then changing to Completed, but not 2 separate txns as above (where Payment changes to Authorized for the first?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you must be running actual Authorizations that you're then capturing later..??  Is that not the case?  In such a case you would get a transaction ID for the original authorization and then another one for the captured transaction.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response. Yes we are getting 2 separate transactions with unique id's for the same amount via a transactionSearch. However when we first query transactions for the customer over the date rage when they have just been created within a few hours they are both returned as type='Payment' status='Complete;. The earlier transaction's state changes to 'Authorization' only when we query the transactions at a later time. NB this happens intermittently-cannot reproduce in a test environment, normally authorization txns are returned with status='Authorization' as expected.